# Should I email a professor during Christmas and New Year Holidays?

Tags: professorship, research-undergraduate, email, supervision, projects

I got a project confirmation from a professor 2 days ago. The project would require me to travel abroad during the summer vacation period of May-July 2021. The formalities such as offer letter and visa forms are pending. The professor told me that he would be on vacation for a few weeks but would be in touch via mail. I sent him my academic records yesterday but I haven't received a reply from him.

Should I wait and send a mail after Christmas? Should I contact him in January?

He was enthusiastic about offering me the position and I'm sorta panicking. Would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give it a rest.  If you mailed him yesterday, you don't need to mail-bomb him again today.  Wait for him to respond, perhaps after Christmas.